# Loop through big Javascript object with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How to loop throught very big object elements without causing browser to hang?

I can easily loop thru array with `setTimeout`/`setInterval` like this:

```
var i = 0;
var l = arr.length;
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
   var k = 100; // process 100 items on each Timeout
   var element;
   while(k--) {
      if (i == l) {
          return clearInterval(interval);
      }
      element = arr[i++];
      // ... work here ...
   }
}, 100);
```

**But what are my options for very big objects?**

- Reading keys first `for(k in arr)` is not an option because it will be one big loop which I want to avoid.
- I can't `.splice()` object because it's not an array.

Currently I am creating array like this `[{k: .., v:...},{k: .., v:...},{k: .., v:...},{k: .., v:...},{k: .., v:...},{k: .., v:...},{k: .., v:...},...]` but it's such a waste of space.

Comment: Define "very big object elements"

Comment: Object.keys() gives you an array of property names you can iterate over.

Comment: [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or server side are good alternatives for threaded work. But only on modern browsers for web workers.

Comment: @CasparKleijne 100,000,000,000 elements. very big :) joking aside people use old computers and even small object with 1000 elements can make browser hang

Comment: Reduce k/timeout interval, or maybe use web workers if there are actually 100 billion elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.keys to do exactly the same logic with objects

```
var i = 0;
var keys = Object.keys( myObj );
var l = keys.length;
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
   var k = 100; // process 100 items on each Timeout
   var element;
   while(k--) {
      if (i == l) {
          return clearInterval(interval);
      }
      element = myObj[ keys[i++] ];
      // ... work here ...
   }
}, 100);
```

But for millions and millions of keys, you should look for different solutions, since you don't want to loop over that many. Maybe split everything into batches and such.

Hence my question becomes, are there times when you actually need millions of objects in memory at the same time, since this sounds like a design issue.

Comment: ignore "milions" i was only joking, your answer is perfect. for object with 100000 elements `Object.keys` return value in less than 30ms. In reality I have much smaller object to process but I rather take extreme cases as test cases.